# Can I increase the maximum Forge/Vanilla ID limit, or remove it entirely?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I installed 200+ mods for my modpack and my self and this error come up:

```
pw.mods.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid id 9884 - maximum id range exceeded.
```

By reading this I can tell that Forge set up ID limits. Is there a way to increase it, or remove/disable it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: As far as I have found, in the past, **meta defines "banned modded minecraft tech support" as questions specific to "here is a crash log, why is it crashing"**. This is not a crash question, nor does it have any of the other problems we associate with bad minecraft questions. I've said this in the past, if we actually ban **all minecraft mod questions**, please provide links to the meta. Opinion is pretty irrelevant, here.

Comment: @Timelord64 No, tech support is anything needed to get mods running.  It's not limited to crashes, as we have closed **many** questions regarding mods not working, but not crashes.  When boiled down, it can be easily defined as, "We don't help get modded Minecraft working.  It includes, but is not limited to, crashes."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41783/discussion-between-frank-and-timelord64).

Comment: I would like to reopen this question _as an exception_ to our ban on the troubleshooting of modded minecraft questions. The answer to this question does not depend on the specific mod that causes the crash, which alleviates many of the problems of intractability that the category carries. The community also received both the question and the answer positively, which emboldens me. It's true, we have guidelines to the contrary, but we should also allow ourselves to be nuanced by the specifics of the individual case when it makes sense.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Questions about modded minecraft crashing have been ruled to be off-topic as a category, regardless of their individual merits. Thus, this question is off-topic and should not have been reopened.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about modded Minecraft. We only support vanilla minecraft error questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minecraft actually allows item IDs up to 32767, but I believe block IDs only go up to 4096. You have a mod that is trying to add a **block** with ID 9884 - which is greater than the maximum block ID.

You might need to install another Forge mod like [this one](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/wip-mods/2467198-notenoughids-maximum-id-range-exceeded-no-more) that extends the possible block IDs up.